# Is it possible to save a generated image in Codename One?

Tags: image, drawing, codenameone, stacked

My question is related to  [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552960/writing-a-string-at-a-given-position-in-a-drawing-in-codename-one). What I want to achieve is to stack images (they have transparency), write a string on top, and save the photomontage / photocollage with full resolution.

```
    @Override
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {


    Image photoBase = fetchResourceFile().getImage("Voiture_4_3.jpg");
    Image watermark = fetchResourceFile().getImage("Watermark.png");


    f.setLayout(new LayeredLayout());
    final Label drawing = new Label();
    f.addComponent(drawing);


    // Image mutable dans laquelle on va dessiner (fond blanc)
    Image mutableImage = Image.createImage(photoBase.getWidth(), photoBase.getHeight());
    drawing.getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage(mutableImage);
    drawing.getUnselectedStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);

    // Paint all the stuff
    paints(mutableImage.getGraphics(), photoBase, watermark, photoBase.getWidth(), photoBase.getHeight());

    // Save the collage
    Image screenshot = Image.createImage(photoBase.getWidth(), photoBase.getHeight());
    f.revalidate();
    f.setVisible(true);
    drawing.paintComponent(screenshot.getGraphics(), true);

    String imageFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "screenshot.png";
    try(OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(imageFile)) {
        ImageIO.getImageIO().save(screenshot, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
    } catch(IOException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void paints(Graphics g, Image background, Image watermark, int width, int height) {

    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    g.drawImage(watermark, 0, 0);
    g.setColor(0xFF0000);

    // Upper left corner
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);

    // Lower right corner
    g.setColor(0x00FF00);
    g.fillRect(width - 10, height - 10, 10, 10);

    g.setColor(0xFF0000);
    Font f = Font.createTrueTypeFont("Geometos", "Geometos.ttf").derive(220, Font.STYLE_BOLD);
    g.setFont(f);
    // Draw a string right below the M from Mercedes on the car windscreen (measured in Gimp)
    g.drawString("HelloWorld", 
            (int) (848 ),
            (int) (610)
            );

}
```

This is the saved screenshot I get if I use the Iphone6 skin [image: Screenshot I get] (the payload image is smaller than the original one and is centered). If I use the Xoom skin this is what I get [image: Screenshot I get with Xoom] (the payload image is still smaller than the original image but it has moved to the left).

So to sum it all up : why is the saved screenshot with Xoom skin different from the one I get with Iphone skin ? Is there anyway to directly save the  graphics on which I paint in  the paints method so that the saved image would have the original dimensions ?

Thanks a lot to anyone that could help me :-)!

Cheers,

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to follow the previous question as it is exceedingly long. I suggest breaking down questions to smaller individual questions to get better responses. Feel free to ask as many questions as you like as long as they are well phrased/researched

Comment: @Shai Right the previous post is too long. Do you recommend to edit it and make it KISS ?

Comment: I recommend writing multiple smaller questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can save an image in Codename one using the [ImageIO](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/util/ImageIO.html) class. Notice that you can draw a container hierarchy into a mutable image using the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.

You can do both approaches with draw image on mutable or via layouts. Personally I always prefer layouts as I like the abstraction but I wouldn't say the mutable image approach is right/wrong.

Notice that if you change/repaint a lot then mutable images are slower (this will not be noticeable for regular code or on the simulator) as they are forced to use the software renderer and can't use the GPU fully.

In the previous question it seems you placed the image with a "FIT" style which naturally drew it smaller than the containing container and then drew the image on top of it manually... This is problematic.

One solution is to draw everything manually but then you will need to do the "fit" aspect of drawing yourself. If you use layouts you should position everything based on the layouts including your drawing/text.

Comment: thanks for your guide! I will try to draw on a mutable image so that the outcome has the same resolution as the original image that will come from the camera. As soon as I get something I will post the code I use.

Comment: It may be trivial @Shai, but what do you mean by "manually" ? An example would be great if ever possible!

Comment: When I say manually I mean using drawString, drawImage etc. like you did directly on the graphics as opposed to paintComponent.